# Who is this black haired girl with a massive sword and gun

Tags: black-rock-shooter

I found this anime picture:

[image] [Source](http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/anime/1_other_anime/19319_1_other_anime_anime_girls_weapons_anime_girl_with_weapon.jpg)

And I'm wondering from which anime it is.
Unfortunately I can't give any more information since I don't know what it's about or anything.
I only have the picture.

PS: I used the google search picture as suggested when adding the tags. But all I came across was people using this as profile picture and only 1.5 page of search results in google. [Search results](https://www.google.be/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitQcsV65coDUMU-cyG_1RS54lBua9fKoXUjnhLoBrMDUDIl0q432_1cdGWlLrp21W7dV1RA-hxyiYpp0tFxpxoni60CMLXM0sr5ekYj3vlGITlcUg7tcV84QI1bDfG3RdyKmqtIeY0uI3f682ROk4kmKpVrzoPF_1Eb7dXB3t7wsEPNFEMPnxLPQozEZltKtwV-gNnxe4kXNZQtw1h8j39j1ywzU4ailUZLHJiImbvi6Fp2L5u1_1XVMpCFHttouTzOYaS49IC4mPtCWW9eVIswPHQMle-v9ktpn25wMhrJQEegnIrYezzGVHY4AzH2iLo8TnZQTSr4mp7Vm1PbI6ST2UZNV-1UAV1B3tbg7l2i7Ygi98OfW_18ItDUyTxw8ddg4F6dcV88f5aXnlZ-a9BnmOziJbLRswdCkjnAOyrBgBIDAaDfoTJWBIrUt_1Kv3rodFfg_1rXPhfdqNxiaKgJ_1m4LqpSed_1Tj6rN8lbKpI3432riunbwpnS60i4-plFGJA2u1ruEsfI6flOJ7496xH-rZ9nQcwyWZ4tBPcH5Pepn6y1f51u8uKG2i1c5qVdahbgf3kNpPW5ibSd9babveIFsVKc1G1CfXBLBdWwsFUr-PKpqORLVH2NkIWdzlCzfnAa6v787hil_1smCAseZVCSTW_1GLrLtXaCgumPv2KvhkJNnabhgCROPLwfZYe41Izj6RqVdc3x0xTkf2kE5IA_1_1ZQqkb4mKLV6FyU4nkja2eigFwKEggTAuwwPmBbixoiBNRlLD_1hyJ-YkMTqVO82bZHfNmtPYqK8hXs6rFTO5Qk5Vr4VZSuad9Z5KGnbCK4irD0tDI73-FebY4khnq6ParK9fLfMeYE7cBfb_1-ZPavNtG2-tMD0HT9OG1SK3LJ1exEM3wdpXzhYkPBJxRnU5Y3n931--xYUw4lqueRGkkF8JNFxsZ9FcXhHjj3yhTFXVqgceqEopdhMffAxBibmsWW-6kghHJm7OObZk2f5dTQVhfogy22OFBXC_1-scR0qfQpna5ACMgxwuLDUdgnPrsQTrFtdnSHMJYHl2nh-qFDrYyphdO2cKxkFE2YR3Zk8KM3oJF4vXWkDi_1eGHXEcS0zxP5eYbtVZj2rvPPVWAWOrezXk1RLkKBzfLteGIHTEQr43S4ODyq23wfqv2sdHEL0Fx--gpGAC38kdIE2kK0HPiPniqvDPqTcBZy5VzgHFs84ScbteaWJuCIBcSGE6o1qfV4mvOF2lYFsEGeVbBP6Bt8cBZN7Ke_1JLf2CNiT7j0X-8KlF0Rv8leACZoKcFtlleAbuFeUD4jfCXB6Y2a1KIL-cWLidpZrNJPv3Ye0lkdfzl9rtP5htY2tc_1olhKNi5JFEBpOQQ_1mhh-U5ixIfOeGCkIUzyOWUn_1Fez7I2ivtbPsljCe6MXRizqhUIISHsC9AzyaCXYCc9480AcWpu3yfOoMVbIa7OGa9D0LuYa5ZxgtxsN5BPFdNMRHNvh4UfALEtBLCSlWzsIQ&ei=0N4AVKTEPIb8ywOPsIL4Bg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1527&bih=877)

I hope some of you know from which anime this is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Black Rock Shooter (anime & character both have the name). It originally was a drawing from Ryohei Fuke on Pivix. This later spawned an OVA and subsequent anime series in 2012 and also a PSP game

[image]

Original Design

> Black★Rock Shooter (ブラック★ロックシューター Burakku Rokku Shūtā?) [...] revolves around its eponymous character, a mysterious black haired girl with a blazing blue eye.
>
> The original illustration inspired a song of the same name by Supercell, which gained popularity on the Nico Nico Douga website. A 50-minute original video animation based on the franchise was produced by Yutaka Yamamoto's studio Ordet, written by Nagaru Tanigawa and Shinobu Yoshioka, and directed by Shinobu Yoshioka. A "Pilot Edition" was released on DVD and Blu-ray Disc in September 2009, before the full version was released on DVDs bundled with select magazines from July 24, 2010, subtitled in seven languages, followed by a retail release on December 17, 2010. An eight-episode television anime series, produced by Ordet and Sanzigen, aired on Fuji TV's Noitamina programming block between February 2 and March 22, 2012. The franchise has also spawned several manga series and a video game for the PlayStation Portable titled Black Rock Shooter: The Game, each set in their own universe.

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Rock_Shooter)

If you want to watch/play you don't have to worry about the order too much as the stories are separate

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, the character from the picture in the question is [*Insane Black Rock Shooter*](http://blackrockshooter.wikia.com/wiki/Insane_Black%E2%98%85Rock_Shooter), the antagonist form of the titular main protagonist character *Black Rock Shooter*.

> Compared to Black★Rock Shooter, Insane Black★Rock Shooter has purple eyes with a flame of the same color emerging from her left eye and fangs.